# "IOError: decoder zip not available" : Ubuntu Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

I am trying to get the sample heatmap.py running from:
http://jjguy.com/heatmap/

```
#image.py
import heatmap
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    pts = []
    for x in range(400):
        pts.append((random.random(), random.random() ))

    print "Processing %d points..." % len(pts)

    hm = heatmap.Heatmap()
    img = hm.heatmap(pts)
    img.save("classic.png")
```

and I get this error:

```
Processing 400 points...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2usr/workspace/image/image.py", line 14, in <module>
    img.save("classic.png")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1437, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 572, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 399, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder zip not available
```

Working off of Eclipse on an Ubuntu 12 (64bit) system, with Python 2.7.

I find libz.so in both /usr/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ just fine.  I've tried these solutions already without result:

[PIL says it has "support available" but still gives IOError when saving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626062/pil-says-it-has-support-available-but-still-gives-ioerror-when-saving-files)

[About the PIL Error -- IOError: decoder zip not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/need-help-with-a-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available)

[IOError: "decoder zip not available" using matplotlib PNG in ReportLab on Linux, works on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073455/ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available-using-matplotlib-png-in-reportlab-on-linux)

http://www.foxhop.net/ubuntu-python-easy_install-pil-does-not-install-zlib-support

I've been pulling my hair out over this for a few days and greatly appreciate anyone's help!

Install Log from python-imaging:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-241-17-21:/usr/lib$ sudo apt-get install python-imaging
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-identica account-plugin-twitter gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0
  hplip-data libgtkspell-3-0 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libsane-hpaio
  linux-headers-3.5.0-21 linux-headers-3.5.0-21-generic python-debtagshw
  python-lxml python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client python-qt4
  python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-sip
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins ubuntu-extras-keyring
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  python-imaging-doc python-imaging-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-imaging
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/294 kB of archives.
After this operation, 996 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-imaging.
(Reading database ... 189302 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-imaging (from .../python-imaging_1.1.7-4build1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up python-imaging (1.1.7-4build1) ...
ubuntu@ip-10-241-17-21:/usr/lib$
```

log from install ( python install setup.py from Imaging) :

```
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14)
              [GCC 4.7.2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
*** JPEG support not available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

selftest.py:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** PIL CORE support not installed
*** TKINTER support not installed
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you have `libz.so` there when you installed PIL?

Comment: I believe so, but I also reintalled PIL egg with sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging afterwards, just in case.

Comment: update: .tif works ok; png and jpg don't work.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly PIL prints a list of supported and unsupported formats during the installation.

Comment: just added the install log from console, didn't see anything on formats.

Comment: Wait, so you think you are using the module from the distribution package?

Comment: sorry, you're right, I didn't include the right log from console. From the install is now added above. JPEG not available.

Comment: I also just added selftest.py above.  There it says that JPEG and ZLIB are indeed supoorted, but PIL Core is not. Now I am really confused.  Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered a similar issue caused by having both PIL (installed through the python pip installer) and the python-imaging package installed via apt-get. When I removed the extra version from pip that resolved it for me.

If you installed PIL from source or using pip then you might have the same problem.

When I was building PIL I also discovered that I had to link over the libraries to /usr/lib. That might resolve the not supported messages in your log above.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 7):

I remember arriving at the exact same solution as Kris did when installing PIL on 64 bit systems.

However nowadays I would recommend using Pillow (pip install pillow) instead of PIL. Pillow is simply a fork of PIL with more frequent releases and less issues like the one you're experiencing.

If you're on Ubuntu I think you need zlib1g-dev and libjpeg-dev installed **before** installing PIL/Pillow so that you get support for jpeg/png built in.

Comment: Here to confirm that you need to install dependencies before installing PIL/Pillow, so the installation process performs the proper compilation steps.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me and it works on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 both with python 2.7 and 3.4

Answer (score 2):

Even though my PIL was up to date, I resolved this on Ubuntu 12.04 with:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install PIL
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked Perfectly for me:

```
apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

In x86_64:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
```

In i386:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/lib/
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/


pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
pip install -I pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

even you test with

> **from PIL import image**

is okay, but there is still error on save/decode methods.

you can try my steps: (base on my case, openerp 7 with ubuntu 13.10)

1. remove python image
2. locate your libz
3. reinstall PIL

check it http://febru.soluvas.com/2014/03/solved-openerp-7-ioerror-decoder-zip.html