# How to correctly use PIL with Python under windows?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a windows 8 box with ActivePython 2.7 32-bit installed. I install PIL via:

```
pypm install pil
```

All works fine, but if i try to use 'save' functionality with 'png', like this:

```
import PIL.Image
PIL.Image.new( 'RGB', (100,100) ).save( 'file.png' )
```

I got an error:

```
File "C:\Users\Eye.DEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 401, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder zip not available
```

This is strange, since `import zlib` works fine, so my ActivePython installation apparently has `zip` suport. Is it some bug and `PIL` is not intended to be used on Windows / installed as binary, or i'm doing something wrong?

Please note, that this behaviour is Windows-specific. All works fine under buntu/Debian or OSX.

Comment: A similar question without answer but with a number of links to possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258335/ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available-ubuntu-python-pil

Comment: @JanneKarila Question you have mentioned is related to `linux` setup with multiple `python` installations. And i have a clean `Windows` box with single `ActivePython` installed - so all problems mentioned in other question can't be applied here :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `PIL` is not maintained and is not compatible with `pip`/`pypm` etc. If `pillow` fork is used, all works just fine.