# IOError: encoder zip not available ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib, python-imaging-library

I getting following error when I am trying to run my python program which uses PIL.

```
Generate_Dot.py:14: RuntimeWarning: the frombuffer defaults may change in a future release; for portability, change the call to read:
  frombuffer(mode, size, data, 'raw', mode, 0, 1)
  img = Image.frombuffer('L', size, data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Generate_Dot.py", line 15, in <module>
    img.save('image.png')
  File "/home/kapil/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/kapil/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 572, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/home/kapil/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/home/kapil/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 401, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder zip not available
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3544155/645956

Comment: possible duplicate of ["IOError: decoder zip not available" : Ubuntu Python PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258335/ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available-ubuntu-python-pil)

Comment: the answer in the duplicate doesn't suit him because he doesn't have root access.

Comment: I already read the above links and tried but no luck. :-(

Answer (score 0):

cpython depends on various third party libraries being installed in your system. In this case 'zip' is required to perform some compression. I'm guessing in this case it would be one of gzip, compress, or zlib. You should be able to install these quite easily using yum, or apt-get.

Comment: I don't have root permission to download and install it by apt-get. I installed zlib from source in my home directory but am stuck at how to link it to my python installed in home directory.

Comment: ad the directory with libz.so to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: e.g. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/mylibs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: try adding to `PYTHONPATH` maybe.